# What to do when mandb fails to update index cache during update?

Tags: apt, upgrade, manpage

I ran a `dist-upgrade` today and this was the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gnome-mines libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-0:i386 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data
  libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-doc libspice-server1 qtox
9 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 12.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 4,531 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 gnome-mines amd64 1:3.20.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1 [2,441 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-dev amd64 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1 [1,377 kB]
Get:3 https://pkg.tox.chat/debian nightly/wily amd64 qtox amd64 1.4.0-192-g279225c-1 [4,328 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-bin amd64 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1 [39.4 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 libglib2.0-0 i386 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1 [1,184 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-0 amd64 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1 [1,118 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-data all 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1 [132 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-doc all 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1 [1,471 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libspice-server1 amd64 0.12.6-4ubuntu0.1 [338 kB]
Fetched 12.4 MB in 15s (783 kB/s)                                              
(Reading database ... 242183 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libglib2.0-data_2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libglib2.0-data (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) over (2.48.0-1ubuntu4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libglib2.0-dev_2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglib2.0-dev (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) over (2.48.0-1ubuntu4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libglib2.0-bin_2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglib2.0-bin (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) over (2.48.0-1ubuntu4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libglib2.0-0_2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.48.0-1ubuntu4) ...
Unpacking libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) over (2.48.0-1ubuntu4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libglib2.0-0_2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) over (2.48.0-1ubuntu4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-mines_1%3a3.20.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-mines (1:3.20.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) over (1:3.20.0-2~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libglib2.0-doc_2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libglib2.0-doc (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) over (2.48.0-1ubuntu4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libspice-server1_0.12.6-4ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libspice-server1:amd64 (0.12.6-4ubuntu0.1) over (0.12.6-4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../qtox_1.4.0-192-g279225c-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking qtox (1.4.0-192-g279225c-1) over (1.4.0-189-gfd2e585-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
/usr/bin/mandb: warning: can't update index cache /var/cache/man/index.db: Resource temporarily unavailable
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libglib2.0-data (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Setting up libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Setting up libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Setting up libglib2.0-bin (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Setting up libglib2.0-dev (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Setting up gnome-mines (1:3.20.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Setting up libglib2.0-doc (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Setting up libspice-server1:amd64 (0.12.6-4ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up qtox (1.4.0-192-g279225c-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47ubuntu1) ...
```

You will see this error comes up:

```
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
/usr/bin/mandb: warning: can't update index cache /var/cache/man/index.db: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Is there any way I can tell why this happened (if there is not an obvious one)? And is there anything I can/need to do as it seems to have failed with updating the `man` index cache? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20.

**Information Update:**

Running `sudo mandb` outputs:

```
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/en_CA...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/en_CA...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/km...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/km...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/sr...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/sr...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/be...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/be...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ta...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ta...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ne...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ne...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/lt...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/lt...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ms...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ms...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/hi...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/hi...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/et...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/et...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/zh_TW...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/zh_TW...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/de.UTF-8...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/de.UTF-8...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ja...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ja...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/tr...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/tr...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/bg...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/bg...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/az...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/az...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ps...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ps...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/pa...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/pa...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/nl...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/nl...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/th...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/th...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/es...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/es...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/zh_CN...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/zh_CN...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/da...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/da...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/pl...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/pl...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/fi...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/fi...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/fr...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/fr...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/fa...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/fa...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/fy...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/fy...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/lv...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/lv...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/en_AU...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/en_AU...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/cs...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/cs...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/sk...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/sk...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/sl...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/sl...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/gl...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/gl...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/zh_HK...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/zh_HK...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/io...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/io...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ca...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ca...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/he...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/he...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/pt...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/pt...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/cy...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/cy...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/oc...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/oc...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/bs...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/bs...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ro...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ro...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/hu...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/hu...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ce...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ce...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ja.UTF-8...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ja.UTF-8...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/te...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/te...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ku...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ku...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/kk...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/kk...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/gd...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/gd...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/id...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/id...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/eo...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/eo...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/pt_BR...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/pt_BR...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ug...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ug...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/it...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/it...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ko...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ko...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/shn...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/shn...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/hy...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/hy...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/mhr...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/mhr...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/se...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/se...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/de...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/de...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ca@valencia...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ca@valencia...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/sq...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/sq...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/nn...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/nn...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/bo...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/bo...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/uk...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/uk...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/eu...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/eu...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ar...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ar...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/hr...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/hr...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/vi...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/vi...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/el...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/el...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/zh...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/zh...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/si...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/si...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/uz...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/uz...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/fr_CA...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/fr_CA...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/my...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/my...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/sv...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/sv...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/fo...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/fo...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/nb...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/nb...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ml...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ml...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/en_GB...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/en_GB...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/bn...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/bn...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ast...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ast...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ru...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ru...
Processing manual pages under /usr/local/man...
0 man subdirectories contained newer manual pages.
0 manual pages were added.
0 stray cats were added.
0 old database entries were purged.
```

Comment: Try running `sudo mandb`, that should update the manpage database.

Comment: @ByteCommander: I have updated my question with the relevant information.

Comment: Looks like nothing needs to be done...?

Comment: @ByteCommander: So what was the error about? Is there any way I can check the package it was updating it for and then check if I have the latest manpage for that package?

Comment: Don't know. I would guess that there was no change and not bother much about it, but since it's you... Can't help you further, sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error indicates that more than one mandb process was running at the same time and thus part of the cache update has failed. It is impossible really to know which part of the installation process had 2 or more calls on the cache leading to the failure.

If there is some concern that the man page database is *incomplete* the following command will refresh the database:

```
sudo mandb
```

Running this reveals the refresh process at work:

```
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/fr_CA...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/fr_CA...
Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/sq...
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/sq...
```

If however the mandb database has become *corrupt*, which is very unlikely in the scenario that you have mentioned, you can try running the more radical command:

```
sudo mandb --create
```

From the man pages for mandb:

```
-c, --create
    By default, mandb will try  to  update  any  previously  created
    databases. If  a  database  does not exist, it will create it.
    This option forces mandb to delete previous  databases  and  re-
    create  them  from scratch, and implies --no-purge.  This may be
    necessary if a database becomes corrupt or if a new database 
    storage scheme is introduced in the future.
```

When you will run this command you will see that a whimsical developer has used the idea of searching for stray cats in the effort to recreate and rebuild the database:

```
Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/hr...
Updating index cache for path `/usr/share/man/hr/man1'. Wait...done.
Checking for stray cats under /usr/share/man/hr...
Checking for stray cats under /var/cache/man/hr...
```

:)

**References:**

- [Xenial: mandb man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/mandb.8.html)
- [Debian Bug report logs - #684235](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=684235)